# Python if statement with two conditions - truth value of array ambiguous

Tags: python, list, numpy

----last update----
A variable definition of the variable 'mtindex' had a comma instead of a dot causing python to return two values for the truth condition.

----Updated question----
I get an error when running an if statement inside a for loop.

My for loop first defines two variables 'pctchange' and 'pctchangeindex' as integers based on a value extracted from a dataframe. So these are defined as a new value for each x value the loop runs through. I then compare the difference between these two to another variable (integer) defined outside of this loop. I do this through an if statement which runs inside the for loop - so that for each new assignment of values to my two loop variables this if condition is tested:

```
for x in range(1,numdays-holdperiod1):
    pctchange = (int taken from dataframe)
    pctchangeindex = (int taken from dataframe)

    if ((pctchange - pctchangeindex) > mtindex and x-1 not in  
    positioncheck1) :
        calculate some things
```

When this is run the line with the if statement gives me the error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I haven't been able to solve this. What I have tested is that I get the same error when i remove the second part of the if statement - so it shouldn't be the 'and' thats giving the error. I would expect that since the if statement is indented relative to the for loop it's run for each new assignment to the variables in the for loop? I hope that my question is more clear this time and that I get some response, since this problem has been stopping me for months.

----Old question----
I have an if statement with two conditions inside a function definition. The part that brings up an error is this:

```
 if (pctchange - pctchangeindex > mtindex and x-1 not in positioncheck1) :
```

I get the exact error in Pycharm:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I have seen other threads decribing the same error and saying it's caused by numpy interpreting arrays differently. The second part of the if condition checks whether or not a given value is in 'positioncheck1' - which is a standard python list.

Comment: Also mention the content your variables are holding

Comment: tell us what all variables have/are?

Comment: What is your question? And the error message tells you what the problem is and what to do.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

This might work:

```
if ((pctchange - pctchangeindex > mtindex).all() and x-1 not in positioncheck1)
```

There are 2 issues.

- operator order.  Put () around the `>` so it is evaluated first.
- multiple boolean values.  `>` acting on arrays creates an array with boolean values.  Those are 'ambiguous' when used in a scalar Python context (`and` and `if`).  I added the `all` (or `any`) to condense those values down to one.

The multiple `ValueError` SO questions all deal with some variation of this problem - a boolean array being used in a scalar Python context.

Here are some sample cases:

```
In [416]: np.arange(10)>6 | True
Out[416]: array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [417]: (np.arange(10)>6) | True
Out[417]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Without `()`, the `|` is evaluated before `>`

With `and`, the boolean array has to be reduced to a scalar first

```
In [418]: np.arange(10)>6 and True
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
In [419]: (np.arange(10)>6) and True
...
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In [420]: (np.arange(10)>6).all() and True
Out[420]: False
```

Comment: I don't see the first issue. What would be wrongly evaluated before `>`?

Comment: With `and` it probably isn't an issue; with operators like `|` and `&` it is.  Anyways there's no harm in using extra `()`, even if all they do is improve readability.

Comment: It's `and`, though, and that does have lower precedence. So I think calling that an issue is misleading.

Comment: I'm just anticipating the next question, when you try `arr>50 & 20<arr`.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found out why the error of the ambiguous truth value was returned. The variable `mtindex` of type int was stated with a comma instead of a dot - which made python interpret it as 2 separate values thus giving two truth statements.

Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15657508)

Comment: As far as I can see this is the answer to my specific situation since the error I had made in my variable definition was what caused the error. But I can see that you might consider this more of a cancelled question than one actually answered. I have updated the question.